# Почему не создаётся функция TransactSQL?

Tags: функции, sql

Пытаюсь создать функцию в SQL Server 2008. Тело функции рабочее и отлаженное. При создании функции получаю ошибку:

```
Сообщение 178, уровень 15, состояние 1, процедура WritersAggregateFunc, строка 37
Инструкцию RETURN с возвращаемым значением нельзя использовать в данном контексте.
Сообщение 102, уровень 15, состояние 31, процедура WritersAggregateFunc, строка 42
Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "BEGIN".
```

Что неправильно?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[WritersAggregateFunc]
(   
    @BookId int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @result varchar(2000)
DECLARE @current varchar(200)
SET @result = ''

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT    (l_Writers.Name)
    FROM         l_BooksWriters INNER JOIN
                      l_Writers ON l_BooksWriters.AuthorID = l_Writers.AuthorID
    WHERE     (l_BooksWriters.BookID = @BookID)

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @current

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @result = ISNULL(@result + ', ' + @current, @current) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @current
END
CLOSE cur

DEALLOCATE cur
SET @result = RIGHT(@result, LEN(@result) - 1)

RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    SELECT @result
)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас неправильный синтаксис функции. Вот рабочи пример, из которого все должно быть ясно

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestTableFunc
(
    @parameter INTEGER
)
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
    ID INTEGER
    ,Name NVARCHAR(256)
)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Разные манипуляции с данными

    -- Теперь заталкиваем данные в результирующую таблицу
    INSERT INTO
        @result
        (ID, Name)
    VALUES
        (1, '1')
        ,(2, '2');

    RETURN;

END
```

Comment: Вы правы! Сделал по образу и подобию Вашего примера.